# Set Dropdown List Selected Value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a dropdown list in an ASP.NET MVC view using AJAX:

```
Url="/Channel/GetChannels";
$.ajax({
    url:Url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ddlChannel").empty();
        $("#ddlChannel").append("<option value='0'>All</option>");
        $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
            $("#ddlChannel").append("<option value='" + optiondata.Id + "'>" + optiondata.Name + "</option>");
        });
    }
});
$("#ddlChannel option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

This produces the following markup:

```
<select id="ddlChannel">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">New Homes</option>
<option value="2">Sales</option>
<option value="3">Lettings</option>
</select>
```

Would someone please tell me how I can select an option value using jQuery.

I have tried:

```
$("#ddlChannel option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with `value=1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set value in the success callback method of `$.fn.ajax()`, as it is asynchronous and also you can use [`$.fn.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set value of select.

*Use*

```
success: function (data) {
    //Your code
    $("#ddlChannel").val(1); 
}
```

Comment: @Satpal If i select anyone of drop-down value all of my dropdown values inserted into the table, how to solve this issue?